# Risks of volatile-mutable fields in single-threaded contexts?

Tags: java, clojure, thread-safety, clojure-java-interop

Is it safe to use the `:volatile-mutable` qualifier with `deftype` in a single-threaded program?  This is a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132931/mutable-fields-in-clojure-deftype/3133655#3133655), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21127636/what-are-the-semantic-implications-of-volatile-mutable-versus-unsynchronized-m), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18236241/setting-a-mutable-field-in-a-nested-function-deftype-clojure/18242407#18242407).  (It's a Clojure question, but I added the "Java" tag because Java programmers are likely to have insights about it, too.)

I've found that I can get a significant performance boost in a program I'm working on by using `:volatile-mutable` fields in a `deftype` rather than atoms, but I'm worried because the docstring for `deftype` says:

> Note well that mutable fields are extremely difficult to use
>   correctly, and are present only to facilitate the building of higher
>   level constructs, such as Clojure's reference types, in Clojure
>   itself. They are for experts only - if the semantics and implications
>   of :volatile-mutable or :unsynchronized-mutable are not immediately
>   apparent to you, you should not be using them.

In fact, the semantics and implications of `:volatile-mutable` are *not* immediately apparent to me.

However, chapter 6 of *Clojure Programming*, by Emerick, Carper, and Grand says:

> "Volatile" here has the same meaning as the volatile field modifier in
>   Java: reads and writes are atomic and must be executed in
>   program order; i.e., they cannot be reordered by the JIT compiler or
>   by the CPU. Volatiles are thus unsurprising and thread-safe — but
>   uncoordinated and still entirely open to race conditions.

This seems to imply that as long as accesses to a single volatile-mutable `deftype` field all take place within a single thread, there is nothing to special to worry about.  (Nothing *special*, in that I still have to be careful about how I handle state if I might be using lazy sequences.)   So if nothing introduces parallelism into my Clojure program, there should be no special danger to using `deftype` with `:volatile-mutable`.

Is that correct?  What dangers am I not understanding?

Comment: If you have a single java thread, and `volatile` has the same meaning as java's volatile - you do not need `volatile` at all.

Comment: atomicity is another issue. you could have concurrency issues even with one thread. But I'm not familiar with Clojure so I can't comment.

Comment: bayou.io: The volatile keyword also enforces that the program order of calls on volatile variables can not be reordered. That might have some use in some case, however I can't think of one.

Comment: Thanks @bayou.io, @ChristopheDeTroyer.  Re single-threaded `volatile` irrelevant: That helps clarify the situation.  (fyi though, in Clojure it's generally rarely possible to do simple assignment to a variable except when the variable was defined in another language such as Java.  `:volatile-mutable` with `deftype` might be the closest Clojure gets to simple assignment to a member variable as in Java.)  Re concurrency/atomiticy issues with one thread: Do you mean when the thread is switching between different tasks?  Re no reordering of calls: I don't think it matters for me, but I don't mind.

Comment: @ChristopheDeTroyer - within a single thread, program orders must be preserved, for all reads/writes. (or actually, reordering could be performed by the compiler/runtime, but it must not be observed by the application; the code is executed in program order, as far as the application can see)

Comment: @Mars - yes, i mean, like time sharing on a single CPU. "volatile" won't be needed, but still, atomicity could be an issue.

Comment: For single threaded use, there is no point to volatile, and unsynchronized-mutable will be faster as you will not have unnecessary memory barriers.

Comment: unsynchronized-mutable is, of course, just a bare field in Java

Comment: @pete23, thank you!  That is *very* helpful information--both comments.  I didn't realize that that's what unsynchronized-mutable meant.  A bare field is something I understand.

Comment: Thank you @SotiriosDelimanolis for the bounty!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's correct, **it's safe**.  You just have to be sure that your context is really single-threaded. Sometimes it's not that easy to guarantee that.

There's no risk in terms of **thread-safety or atomicity** when using a volatile mutable (or just mutable) field in a single-threaded context, because there's only one thread so there's no chance of two threads writing a new value to the field at the same time, or one thread writing a new value based on outdated values.

As others have pointed out in the comments you might want to simply use an `:unsynchronized-mutable` field to avoid the cost introduced by volatile. That cost comes from the fact that every write must be **committed to main memory** instead of thread local memory.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/989846/1389573) for more info about this.

At the same time, you gain nothing by using volatile in a single-threaded context because there's no chance of having one thread writing a new value that will not be "seen" by other thread reading the same field.
That's what a volatile is intended for, but it's irrelevant in a single-thread context.

Also note that clojure 1.7 introduced [`volatile!`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/volatile!) intended to provide a "volatile box for managing state" as a **faster alternative to
atom**, with a similar interface but without it's compare and swap semantics. The only difference when using it is that you call `vswap!` and `vreset!` instead of `swap!` and `reset!`. I would use that instead of
deftype with `^:volatile-mutable` if I need a volatile.

Comment: Thanks--among other things, I didn't know about `volatile!` etc., and it's useful to know about the caching issue.